# Delay jQuery animation until the background image is displayed by Supersized plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

People asked similar questions before, but mine is with a twist:

I'm using Supersized jQuery plugin to load a single full-screen background image. The code loading the image is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

                $.supersized({
                    //Background image
                    slides  :  [ { image : 'http://www.cybart.com/bscg/wp-content/themes/Custom/images/backgrounds/bg.jpg' } ]                  
                });

$('#content').delay(3500).fadeIn(600);

            });


        </script>
```

As you can see in the code, I chained the fadeIn effect after the "supersized" function. I want to fade in the #content div after the background image (bg.jpg) not just finished loading but also finished fading in. I used the solution I don't particularly like: setting a long delay before my fadeIn effect.

What would be the best way to fade in the content div after Supersized image finihsed fading in?

Would be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own answer:

the solution is to edit the supersized core js file. In the file, after this bit of code:

```
$('#supersized-loader').hide();     //Hide loading animation
element.fadeIn('fast');         //Fade in background
resizenow();
```

I added my own line:

```
$('#content').delay('fast').fadeIn('fast');
```

Worked like magic!

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still looking for a solution, here's what I did:

Supersized.3.2.7.js

Right after the **img.load** function, within the **base._start** function, I added the following:

```
img.fadeOut();
img.bind("load", function () { $(this).fadeIn(750); });
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the [jQuery .ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $.supersized({
    //Background image
    slides  :  [ { image : 'http://www.cybart.com/bscg/wp-content/themes/Custom/images/backgrounds/bg.jpg' } ]                  
  });

  $.supersized.ready( function() {
    $('#content').fadeIn(600);
  });

});
```

Comment: Yeah, that would have been nice, wouldn't it Erin? :-) Unfortunately, it wouldn't work. ready() method doesn't wait for images to fade in; it doesn't even wait for images to load. load() method would normally be sufficient, but Supersized plugin seems to be a little more complicated than that, so that type of solution doesn't work with load() either. I would be grateful for more ideas.